# Checking RAW file sended to network printer

Tags: printer, network-printer

I have a problem with tracking down an issue with printing specific types of reports (invoice) from an ERP system on Xerox network printers.

The ERP system use SAP Crystal Reports to generate reports, and I think the problem is not with Crystal Reports because on print preview everything is ok.

From time to time when someone prints to the Xerox network printer there is a gap on print. There is one missing horizontal line (usually the third one from top but not always). On other network printers (OKIs, Konica Minoltas) everything is printed correctly, the problem is only on the Xerox printer. I checked PCL6, XPS and PS type of drivers.  The problem exists on every one (reinstalling a driver helps for sometime).

Is there a way to check ,,RAW'' file sent to the printer from computer with Windows? Any other ideas what can cause a problems?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [SPLVIEWER](http://splviewer.sourceforge.net/) to check what is sent to print device